# Knock out visible binding of anchor tag is not working

Tags: knockout.js, javascript

I am using JavaScript module pattern in my application. 
Here is my html binding

`<a href="#"  data-bind="visible:master.child.showDeleteLink,click: function(obj, event)
                                                     { master.child.showDeletePopup() } ">`

My view modal is

```
    master.child=(function (my, jQuery, ko) {
    var textTemp;
    my.ViewModel = function () {
    self.showDeleteLink = ko.observable();
        self.showDeleteLink = function () {
            if (textTemp.length > 500)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
       }
    ko.applyBindings(my.anothermodule);
    } 
}(master.child, $, ko));
```

Click binding, html are text  are working pretty fine :).

But visiblity binding is not working.any body have any idea? am i wrong any where?

Comment: show the code for `showDeleteLink` please. and if possible provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry @ Circadian. by mistake i forgot to change the variable name.i corrected the variable.i am not able to produce a js fiddle of the problem tried once.

Comment: is the `showDeleteLink` always true or always false? I suspect it has something to do with how you call it (`master.child.showDeleteLink`). Have you tried outputting it using `data-bind="text:showDeleteLink"`

Comment: Yea value is true.Thank you for your time. i got the solution. I changed the existing binding to this `data-bind="visible:master.child.showDeleteLink()` now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my.ViewModel = function () {
    self.showDeleteLink = ko.observable();
        self.showDeleteLink = function () {
            if (textTemp.length > 500)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
       }
```

your "self.showDeleteLink" is no longer observable. You give it a new value, being the function.

I think what you are looking for is a computed value:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

```
self.showDeleteLink = ko.computed(function() {
        return (textTemp.length > 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

change The binding to `data-bind="visible:master.child.showDeleteLink()` now its working pretty fine

Comment: But still am not clear the difference between `data-bind="visible:master.child.showDeleteLink()` and `data-bind="visible:master.child.showDeleteLink` any one have any idea