# knockout visible binding failure

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, single-page-application

I am trying to make some button invisible based on whether a user is loggedIn or not, for this I have done something like:

I have a module called authmodule, which is coded as:

```
define(function () {

var loggedIn = ko.observable(false);  // tried without observable too.

var updateLoginStatus = function () {
    // call the webapi using ajax and intercept the 401
    // if error is 401 set set loggedIn to false and
    // true otherwise.

    // set ajax call
    var options = {
        url: '/breeze/breeze/MicCheck123',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    // make call
    return $.ajax(options)
        .then(function (data) {
            loggedIn(true);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus) {
            if (jqXhr.status == 401 || jqXhr.status == 404) {
                loggedIn(false);
            }
        });
};

// my ko.computed used in html to do visible binding
var isUserLoggedIn = ko.computed(function () {
    updateLoginStatus();
    return loggedIn;
});

var authmodule = {
    isUserLoggedIn: isUserLoggedIn,
    updateLoginStatus: updateLoginStatus
};

return authmodule;
});
```

I am now requiring this authmodule in my shell.js and also returning the same from the viewmodle as shown below

```
define(['durandal/system',
    'services/logger',
    'durandal/plugins/router',
    'config',
    'services/authmodule'],
function (system, logger, router, config, authmodule) {

    var shell = {
        activate: activate,
        authmodule: authmodule,
        router: router
    };
    return shell;

    function activate() {
        return boot();
    }

    function boot() {
        router.map(config.routes);
        return router.activate(config.startModule);
    }
}
);
```

and the html of the corresponding shell.js looks as follows

```
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-secondary">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <!-- ko foreach: router.visibleRoutes -->
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash },
                      css: { active: isActive },
                      html: caption,
                      visible: $parent.authmodule.isUserLoggedIn"
           class="btn btn-info"></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Since I have four visible routes and I expect to see 4 buttons in the top-ribbon when the ajax succeeds and when ajax fails I expect to see no buttons but this does not seem to be working no matter what the ajax result is.

Can someone help me identify what exactly I am missing?

I have already looked at

[Knock out visible binding of anchor tag is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058730/knock-out-visible-binding-of-anchor-tag-is-not-working)

Comment: are you sure that $parent 'll give you the right context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside ko.computed functions you need to call the observable (that is the way ko knows when re-evaluate your computed), like

```
return loggedIn();
```

then when the value of that observable change the computed value is going to be updated as well.

May be in your sample the ajax call should be run only once not inside the computed.

Comment: Marcelo thanks for your reply I tried it and it does work. I am marking this as the answer. The 'subscribe' solution proposed by @Damien above also works but I guess thats not the way to use subscribe. I feel this answer to be more correct.

Comment: I have to say that you should not use computed as event handler. Imagine, if you bind 3 elements to the isUserLoggedIn the computed and the updateLoginStatus will be called 3 times.
But if you want that the updateLoginStatus function be called only when the loggedIn changed you will need to subscribe to the property loggedIn. That's the aim of the subcribe function (to be notified when property changed).

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need the isUserLoggedIn property.

So, in the buttons bindings replace

```
visible: $parent.authmodule.isUserLoggedIn
```

by

```
visible: $parent.authmodule.loggedIn
```

And in the main view model replace :

```
var isUserLoggedIn = ko.computed(function () {
    updateLoginStatus();
    return loggedIn;
});
```

By :

```
loggedIn.subscribe(updateLoginStatus);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this worked, really appreciate it. I guess I need to just sit back and read up about knockout rather than simply reading some blog here and there and attempting things.

Comment: @indichimp: You are welcome. You could take a look at this post 
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html